# Able to ping two linux machines but cannot mount nfs share from one to another

Tags: ubuntu, debian-stretch

Okay so I'm new to all this stuff. I've never worked on Linux servers before. I have an Ubuntu server and Debian stretch ver 9. I installed nfs server on Ubuntu and nfs client on Debian. The machines are able to ping one another but the problem is that when I try to mount nfs share from Ubuntu to debian, it says

```
mount.nfs: connection timed out
```

The command I'm running on Debian is:

```
# mount <ip of Ubuntu>:/export/nfs /mnt/nfs
```

I created `/mnt/nfs` in Debian. Here, `/export/nfs` is the directory I created on Ubuntu and the ownership is `nobody:nogroup`. I also edited the `/etc/exports` and added the following in it:

```
/export/nfs <internal-network>/24(rw,insecure,all_squash).
```

I don't know what the problem is. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Connection timed out would suggest the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the host name of the ubuntu server before the `:` in your command.

For RedHat, but the idea is the same:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/System_Administration_Guide/s1-nfs-mount.html

If the host name is myubuntu and share is /export/nfs then it should be `mount myubuntu:/export/nfs` not just `mount :/export/nfs`

Also, make sure you have iptables open and not blocking the ports.

Comment: did not answer the question, if you check OP he employed every detail you mentioned except you use hostname instead of IP.

Comment: @JonesG the question was edited after my answer and this information was added by a user other than the OP. I don’t know why. The original post exactly what I described, which was the hostname/ip was missing. You can look at the edit history for details.

Answer (score 0):

If the direcotry /mnt/nfs on the client machine doesn't exist already, create it first:

```
mkdir /mnt/nfs
```

It seems to be that you want to mount the share for longer time and not only temporary? If so, anothere location instead of `/mnt` would be preferable, because `/mnt` ist meant for temporary mounts - if not it's ok like that.

If you want to mount it fix, just add this lines to your `/etc/fstab` file:

Open the file with nano for example: `nano /etc/fstab`

> ```
> <ip of Ubuntu>:/export/nfs/    /mnt/nfs    nfs    rw,sync,hard,intr    0    0
> ```

and enter the following command, to mount all entries from `/etc/fstab`

```
mount
```

Using ip or dns-name doesn't matter.

On the Server side, you have to reload the `/etc/exports` file whenever you edit it with the command `exportfs -a`

Also try to restart your nfs-server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart
```

If the systems aren't in the same subnet, check also if a external firewall is between them. With iptables -L you can check, if for a internal firewall on the systems, as well.

Answer (score 0):

escalate privilege if need be using `sudo` prefix

```
$ mount -t nfs -o _netdev,rw,proto=tcp,sec=sys [serverip]:[location] [local mount point]
```

do not forget the underscore preceding netdev

`_netdev` is correct - will prevent from system from hanging if server is not online

example

```
$ mount -t nfs -o rw,_netdev,proto=tcp,sec=sys 10.10.2.1:/mnt/ZFS/PROXMOX/ /media/PROXMOX
```

Running `mount -v` (verbose) may give a clue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).